# What causes a bread dough to become dense?

Tags: baking, bread, dough

I have a stand mixer, but it’s in a box in the garage; I haven’t rescued it since we moved. I consequently use the “mix” cycle on my bread machine to mix and knead the dough. The mix cycle runs 15 minutes. I usually use a whole cycle to mix the dough, let it autolyse for about 15 minutes, then run the “mix” cycle again (and incorporate the fat during the cycle). My doughs seem to come out very dense after baking. Am I kneading the dough too much? Or do I need to adjust my formulas?

Comment: What is your current formula, aka recipe?

Comment: It’s a “quick Brioche,” and I used it to make a twisted chocolate ring. It’s happened with other doughs as well, though. 100% AP Flour, 43% hydration (whole milk), 1% salt, 2.5% active dry yeast, 30% fat (butter), 14% sugar (I used honey), 40% eggs.

Comment: @JustJoel, I know more about beermaking than breadmaking, but at least the usual beer yeasts don't metabolize honey nearly as quickly as other sugars (meads often ferment for nearly a year, compared to a few weeks for ale). You might need to allow more time for rising if you're starting the yeast with honey rather than white sugar.